# vbscript display a database query in html table

Tags: html, mysql, sql, vbscript

I've seen several examples, but all are in ASP or PHP. The company I work for has a lot of security and I'm not allowed to install either of these on my computer for development, therefore, I need to do this in HTML.

I created a form that gathers info from the user and submits it, via VBScript, to a 2010 Access Database. What I need to figure out is how to display this in an HTML table.

Here's the VBScript sub that queries the database for everything in the table:

```
Sub SelectFromDatabase()

    Dim strSQL, strConnect

    Dim conn, rs

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\My Stuff\MyData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    conn.Open strConnect

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SurveyData"

    ' Send the query to the database and save result
    Set rs = conn.Execute strSQL

    ' Close the connection to the database
    conn.Close
    strSQL = ""

end sub
```

I created a separate sub that calls the previous sub and stores the data in variables:

```
sub PrintData
    call SelectFromDatabase()
    strFullName = FullName
    strAddress = Address
    strCity = City
    strState = State
    strZip = Zip
    strPhone = Phone
    strEmail = Email
    strComputer = Computer
    strOS = OS
    strShopping = Shopping
end sub
```

This is the HTML that I'm using to print the data to an HTML table:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Web Site - Customer Data</title>
        <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript" src="Process.vbs">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="SelectFromDatabase();">
        <h1 align=center>My Web Site</h1>
        <h2>Customer Data</h2>
        <p>Below is a list of the customer data that has been submitted.</p>
        <hr>
        <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
            document.writeln("<table border=1><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th><th>Phone</th><th>Email</th><th>Computer</th><th>OS</th><th>Shopping</th></tr>")
            Do Until rs.EOF
                document.writeln("<tr><td>" & rs(0) & "</td><td>" & rs(1) & "</td><td>" & rs(2) & "</td><td>" & rs(3) & "</td><td>" & rs(4) & "</td><td>" & rs(5) & "</td><td>" & rs(6) & "</td><td>" & rs(7) & "</td><td>" & rs(8) & "</td><td>" & rs(9) & "</td></tr>")
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
            document.writeln("</table>")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting is in the `for each...` row. It is saying that `PrintData` is not a collection, which I agree, but I'm not sure now I would call the sub `PrintData` and be able to use the info in an HTML table.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand you correctly. You have a website (not using ASP) that contains a form and the form data is used to query a database on the *client*?

Comment: No. If you please look at the HTML example above, I am trying to print the data to a table. The form is how the data gets entered into the database. I need to pull the data from the database and put it in an HTML table. I can't use PHP or ASP as I am unable to install either of those due to company security.

Comment: Okay, so when you say "form", you mean a form in Access? Not an HTML form? Are you familiar with HTA's? I think you're going to want to go that route. Creating client-side ActiveX controls (i.e. `CreateObject`) in a webpage is going to cause IE to complain. You'll probably have to set IE's security settings to their lowest level to get it to run without prompting you each time (which I wouldn't recommend). See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) for more information on HTA's. Take note of the section entitled "So Why Don’t I Just Use an HTML File?".

Comment: No. Let me be clear. This is a web site created in HTML. The HTML form submits info to an Access database. This is already functional. What I'm trying to do is use **vbscript to display a database query in html table**, hence the title of the question. I could use HTA, as I have in the past, but that's not the issue.

Comment: I understand your question but I can't answer it unless you give me more information. From your code above, the *technical* answer is that you can't. Or, at least, you shouldn't. You're creating *client-side* COM objects. Your "website" is only going to work if all users have those COM objects installed and even then it's a breach of contract, which is why IE typically throws security messages/prompts at you when you try to do this. If you are the only one using this, and if this is a local IIS installation, then you can probably get away with it. But anything else, and you'll have issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment above about switching this over to an HTA. Once you've done that, you can create ActiveX controls (`Connection` objects, `Recordset` objects, etc) to query your database without Internet Explorer complaining.

Your `SelectFromDatabase` function doesn't save the resulting recordset. You're doing a query, which is great, but you're not saving the result set. `Connection.Execute()` returns a `Recordset` object.

```
' in SelectFromDatabase()...
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SurveyData"

' Send the query to the database AND save the result!
Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
```

Now `rs` contains the records returned from your query. `rs(0)` is the value of the first column, `rs(1)` is the value of the second column, and so on. You can loop through these records like so:

```
Do Until rs.EOF
    ' Write to page...
    document.writeln("<tr><td>" & rs(0) & "</td><td>" & rs(1) & "</td></tr>")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

As an alternative to looping, you could also use the `GetString()` function of the `Recordset` class to format all of your records into a table:

```
document.write("<table><tr><td>" & rs.GetString(, , "</td><td>","</td></tr><tr><td>") & "</td></tr></table>")
```

Here's a full, working sample:

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="vbscript">
    Sub SelectFromDatabase()

        Dim cn, rs, e

        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\My Stuff\MyData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

        Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT * FROM SurveyData")

        Set e = document.getElementById("content")
        e.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>" & rs.GetString(2, , "</td><td>", "</td></tr><tr><td>") & "</td></tr></table>"

        rs.Close
        cn.Close

    End Sub
</script>
<body onload="SelectFromDatabase()">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I'm looking for. So, I need `Set rs = conn.Execute strSQL` to create a record set instead of just `conn.Execute strSQL`? Do you recommend the `Do Until` example over your alternative `GetString()`? I'm looking for the best example and I think you are on the right track. :)

Comment: Right. Just like the statement `2 + 2` gets evaluated to `4`, it doesn't do you any good unless you save the result (`x = 2 + 2`). The same thing applies to `Connection.Execute()`. Save the results into a `Recordset` object. As for `Do Until` vs `GetString()`... I wouldn't use `GetString()` with large recordsets -- that is a large number of rows and/or columns. It concats all records into a single string (in memory).

Comment: I tried your `Do Until...Loop`. It's not showing the data in the table. I did what you said about `Set rs = conn.Execute strSQL`. I am getting an "expected end of statement" on that line, the line with the `<body>` tag, and "rs object required" on the line with `Do Until rs.EOF`. Now what am I missing? See my update code in the examples.

Comment: Sorry, I copied that part from your code. When assigning to a variable, you need to use parens when calling functions. I've updated my code above (`Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)`).

Comment: Also, you're defining `rs` within your function. So it has "function scope", which means it's not available outside your function. You'll need to return the recordset as the function return value OR make `rs` a global variable so it's accessible from outside `SelectFromDatabase`. And `PrintData` isn't doing anything useful that I can see, other than calling `SelectFromDatabase`. The rest of the statements are invalid.

Comment: I just posted a small sample. You should be able to use that as a starting point. Good luck!

Comment: I see why it seems like my function scope is unavailable. I forgot to add the `<head>` section of my HTML. I updated the code to show I'm using an external VBScript file named **Process.vbs**. This is where `SelectFromDatabase()` and `PrintData` are located. I want to use the VBS file so that I don't have to type all the scripts into each web page. I can call what I need from one file. I'll try your updated example.

Comment: That's not going to solve your problem. `rs` is defined in `SelectFromDatabase()`. Therefore, it's only available in that function. But later on, you're trying to use it (outside of `SelectFromDatabase`) to loop through your records.

Comment: I just updated my code to resemble what you have posted in your examples. **IT WORKED!!** Thank you very much for your time and patience. :)